# I get an error on Stack Overflow when searching for "C++" questions

Tags: support, search, ignored-tags

I'm getting this error **ONLY WHEN I'M LOGGED IN**. When I search for other tags everything works as expected but when I'm logged in and search for "c++" all found questions appears and then instantly disappear from the list. I get this error on all installed browsers (Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 3 and Chrome).

Here are formal steps to reproduce this:

- Open [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com).
- Log in.
- Enter "C++" in search box and press "Enter" on your keyboard.

**P.S.**: I don't get the same error on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Not reproducible. Neither with Chrome, nor with Firefox. Clear your cache.

Comment: Didn't help. I'll try to debug JS to see when exactly this happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I search for other tags everything works as expected but when I'm logged in and search for "c++" all found questions appears and then instantly disappear from the list

Remove c++ from your ignored tag list, and/or turn off "hide ignored questions".

Comment: Right....... :D